# Banner image doesn't display after directory change

Tags: html, css

I have a banner header that display's its banner image when in the main directory of the site but once I move the HTML file to a sub folder and update all the links to reflect the folder change the banner image no longer displays. In all of my code editors, the path to the image is set correctly. Below you will find the code in my header and also the section of code that isn't working properly. top-banner.jpg is the question at hand here. All other images on the page work and are in the same directory as the banner image. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Products</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/flaticon.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/fopen-sans.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/raleway-webfont.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/lato.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/idangerous.swiper.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>



<div class="wpc-top-header overlay img-bg">
        <img src="../img/top-banner.jpg" alt="banner" class="hidden">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="heading">Our Products</div>
                        <div class="subheding">
                            <a href="index.html" class="link">home</a><span class="round"></span>
                            <a href="#" class="link">pages</a><span class="round"></span>
                            <a href="about.html" class="link active">Our Products</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It has class 'hidden'? Maybe give us a link to the site/code?

Comment: Yeah and the class hidden is setting 'display: none!important;' If you untick that in developer tools you can see the image.

Comment: Added an answer to show the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `class="hidden"` in `<img src="../img/top-banner.jpg" alt="banner" class="hidden">`

---

Edit: As can be seen from the provided links, the file `/htmltest/js/scripts.js` contains:

```
/*-------------------------*/ 
/*  ADD BACKGROUND IMAGE   */ 
/*-------------------------*/


$(".img-bg").each(function(){
    $(this).css("background-image", "url("+$(this).find("img").attr('src')+")");
});
```

However, the path `js/scripts.js` is not updated to `../js/scripts.js`, and this script is not executed. So just replace all `js/`into `../js/` in the HTML file.

Comment: I did try that, and that does display the image now but the text is no longer over the image and now pushed below with a grey area. Why would it work in the main directory fine with the hidden class but not the sub directory?

Comment: Please check your css files if there's some setting for `<img>`. And it's better to give a link to the site so we can help look up the files.

Comment: I've now added links

Comment: I see. There's some JavaScript file add the property `style="background-image: url("img/top-banner.jpg");"` to `<div class="wpc-top-header overlay img-bg">`, so don't forget to update `src` of js files in the end of the html file. And there's no need to remove `class="hidden"` now.

Answer (score 0):

Your old version adds a style into the `div` tag with class `overlay`. Its adding:

```
style="background-image: url("img/top-banner.jpg");"
```

So add that to your new `<div>` but obviously with the new path. That fixes it for me, so to clarify the line should now be:

```
<div class="wpc-top-header overlay img-bg" style="background-image: url('../img/top-banner.jpg');">
```